# Does global picklist supports Localisation?

Tags: apex, metadata-api, global-picklist

Please help me on below points:

1. I have a requirement where I need to make global picklist values as per locale. How can I achieve this. I don't want to use it through custom labels as it has around 300 values.
2. Currently global picklist is in Beta, is it good to use? What is the possible drawback and advantage to use this.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the Translation Workbench supports Global Picklists. You can use those global picklists across multiple objects. The translations will work correctly for every picklist that uses a global picklist. The two major limitations I see are (a) the only valid picklist values are those in the global picklist, unlike regular picklists that *can* have invalid values, and (b) the values do not appear under the individual object fields you create from the global picklist, which means you have to go through an extra click to see the picklist values. They're certainly a lot easier to use than custom labels, especially for the scope that you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks for response. It is in beta version, so is there any problem if I use it in managed package?